# Get Base64 String of Ant Design Multi Upload list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Hi im making a multi upload files button with Ant Design. My goal is update state **fileList** with the list of file and convert **originFileObj** into base64 string. The problem is my function only returns one base64 string for all files in **fileList**. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Upload } from 'antd';

export default class MultiUpload extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fileList: []
    };
    this.handleUpload = this.handleUpload.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpload =  (info: any) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];
    // Accept 5 files only
    fileList = fileList.slice(-5);
    fileList.forEach(function(file, index) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
         file.base64 =  e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(info.file.originFileObj);
    });
    this.setState({fileList: fileList});
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Upload
          listType={"text"}
          multiple={true}
          onChange={this.handleUpload}
        >
          <button >
            Upload
          </button>
        </Upload>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

onСhange function is called with an object with such fields

```
{
   file: {/ * ... * /},
   fileList: [/ * ... * /],
   event: {/ * ... * /},
}
```

You always pass only the current file into readAsDataURL. Instead, you need to pass a file from the fileList.
handleUpload function should look something like this:

```
handleUpload = (info: any) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];
    // Accept 5 files only
    fileList = fileList.slice(-5);
    fileList.forEach(function (file, index) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        file.base64 = e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj);
    });
    this.setState({ fileList });
  };
```